# Why does my express-validator not detect a function?

Tags: node.js, express

I am stuck on how to run my work, my express validator ver:  6.1.1

```
app.use(expressValidator());
        ^
TypeError: expressValidator is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you import/require express-validator?

Comment: Please provide more code.